# Passing parameters to base classes created in class

Tags: c#

I have two classes, lets say A and B, written in C#.

A inherits B, but in the base constructor I want to pass through a field of A.

So:

```
private class A
{
    public A(int number)
    {

    }
}
private class B : A
{
    private int woo;
    public B(int number)
        : base(woo)
    { }
}
```

Is this possible? If not, is there a way around it?

Thanks.

Comment: this is not c# at all it's a c++

Comment: 1) that's not C# 2) in your code B inherits A, not the other way around.

Comment: To be honest I just wrote some sample code quickly, I'll update it.

Comment: If you want to pass it to the constructor, you might want to initialise it first - either in a static constructor, or with its declaration.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about C#:

```
private class A
{
    public A(int number)
    {

    }
}
private class B : A
{
    public B(int number)
        : base(number)
    { }
}
```

Edit for your updated question:

As you have it now, you're passing to the `A` constructor a field in `B`. You aren't able to do that in the way you've described because at the time `B` is constructed, it's field, `woo` has no value because `B` is in the process of being constructed.

My suggestion: Just add another parameter to the `B` constructor. You don't have a value for `woo` anyway at the time because `B` isn't constructed yet. I assume you'll know the value at construction time.

Comment: I am, thanks. I don't even know what I was thinking there, I'll borrow this code if that's okay.

Comment: If I had a patent on this code or pattern I would be the world's richest man in the history of humanity from now until the end of time :). Use away my friend, use away.

Comment: Thank you very much, although I feel like I've lost my chance to have the question answered. ¬_¬

Comment: Quite possibly. If what I posted doesn't answer the question, just update it for clarification and you might gain back some of the negatives.

Comment: Hmm, I updated it to clarify the problem. Not sure if there is a solution though.

Comment: I'll updated my answer to reflect your new question